# Iterate through arbitrary json in backbone/underscore template

Tags: json, backbone.js, underscore.js, template-engine

In the normal case you get the value via the key, that is to get the value of name with <%= name %>, you have to know the key is "name". My question is if you do not know the key of the json field in the first place, how can you iterate through them, for example, dump all the key-value pairs in a table?

Comment: using [`_.forEach()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could transform your object into an array of objects with keys and values as attributes. For example,

```
var obj = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3};

var fields = _.map(
    _.pairs(obj),
    function(pair) {
        return {
            key: pair[0],
            value: pair[1]
        };
    }
);
```

would yield `[{key: "one", value: 1}, {key: "two", value: 2}, {key: "three", value: 3}]`

You can then feed this array into your template, something like

```
var template = _.template(
    '<% _(list).each(function(field) { %>'+
        '<%= field.key %> : <%= field.value %><br>'+
    '<% }); %>'
);
$('body').append(template({
    list: fields
}));
```

And a Fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/kvxuN/

Comment: Thanks so much! Normally I wait for some time before accepting answer but this time no need!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to rebuild your JSON structure.

just try

```
_.each(list,function(key,value,field){
key + ':' + value 

})
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. However, [you have the key and value arguments reversed](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Answer (score 0):

Given JSON where you dont know the `Key` or `Value` such as `{Bob : "01/01/2000", Jane : "10/10/2001"}` and you want to use an Underscore template:

```
options = {Bob : "01/01/2000", Jane : "10/10/2001"}


$.each(options, function (name, age) {
    $("#target-div").append(_.template($("#template-name-age").html(), { Name : name, Age : age }))
})


<script type="text/template" id="template-name-age">
    <div data-name="<%= Name %>" class="some-css-class"><%= Age %></div>
</script>
```